# How can i create a global navigation stack?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I want a global navigation stack. When the user changes tabs or navigates to a new view in the same tab, I want to push the new view onto the global navigation stack. I want the back button in the navigation bar to go back to the previous view, which is sometimes a different tab, and sometimes a different view in the same tab.

[image]

Comment: Peter's answer (below) will work.. but this UI sounds very "Android". Users expect a tab bar to work like a tab bar... this works like no other app I've ever used and will go against users' expectations (bad). Is there another UI you could use to achieve the same effect?

Comment: also, in my opinion, the Yelp app has bad UI and should not be used as an example :)

Answer (score 4):

To achieve this effect, you could ditch the UITabBarController - and emulate the bar by using a custom view or customizing the standard UIToolbar.

Have one navigation controller with, with your customized toolbar always visible, and when buttons are tapped on it, just push the views you want onto the navstack.

Comment: Yes, it's the standard default behavior

Comment: Erm... so what exactly are you having problems with?

Comment: I want all the UIViewController's in the UITabBarController to be loaded into the same UINavigationController

Answer (score 0):

you could achieve  the same by setting the left bar button of your `UINavigationController` as the button of your choice, Handle the action method and invoke the appropriate tabbar button on click event.

You need to do all that in your root view controller ...

**ADDED:**

You could not get the back button on the root view controllers (Navigation controllers;s root view associated with your tabbar instance) just by pressing the tabbar button.

you need to find the way to achieve this as you are not getting this from iOS So The movement you press the tabbar button your need to have the variable that store the previous selected index and a method that give the information for any tabbar by just passing the index ...  So by using these two you could set the title of your left bar button of navigation bar and return to the previous tab by assigning the appropriate action method to  the left bar button ...

Comment: I didn't understand what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You want all the `UIViewController`'s in the `UITabBarController` to be loaded into the same `UINavigationController`?

So something like this:

```
          ___ RootViewController ___
         |                           |
UINavigationController        UITabBarViewController
```

instead of

```
               RootViewController
                        |
     _________ UITabbarViewController _____________________
    |                           |                          |
UINavigationController   UINavigationController    UINavigationController
```

You should try "experimenting" with your own custom `UITabBar`

Comment: Is there any tutorial or something useful (guide...) that can help me to doing that?

Comment: You could create your own 'tabbar', which is nothing more then a bunch of buttons with a desired 'selected' state. I do this all the time, because i "don't like" the default tabbar's UI.

Comment: But if i want to present a modal view controller, the UITabBar will be not hidden...

Comment: I didn't say the `UITabBar` will be hidden ...
Just try to experiment with a 'default' `UINavigationController` and a few `UIButton`'s on the bottom that push `UIViewController`'s to that `UINavigationController`. No need to use a `UITabBarController` for that

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create a global array (NSMutableArray) that will hold NSInvocation objects. So every time you push view controller you need to create NSInvocation with navigation controller as target and `popViewConrollerAnimated:` as selector. If you're tapping the tab bar item you need to  set tab bar controller as target and `setSelectedViewController:` as selector. You should also specify current view controller as parameter using

```
- (void)setArgument:(void *)buffer atIndex:(NSInteger)index
```

Then every time you pop your global stack you need just call `[myLastInvocation invoke]`;

Answer (score 0):

I Had similar issue. I did it like this :

To change the tab, use : say, you want to go at tab 2 and its 3rd view controller

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2;

[self.tabBarController.delegate tabBarController:self.tabBarController didSelectViewController:
     [[[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2] viewControllers] objectAtIndex:3]];
```

Comment: Can you explain more your idea please? :)

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. In my experience I was needed to have `mainTabBarController` and `detailedNavigationController` as two root controllers.
Those two methods of `UIApplicationDelegate` class work perfect:

```
- (void) showDetailedTab 
{
    CGRect normalRect = self.window.bounds;
    CGRect rightRect = CGRectOffset(normalRect, normalRect.size.width, 0);
    CGRect leftRect = CGRectOffset(normalRect, -normalRect.size.width, 0);

    detailedNavigationController.view.frame = rightRect;
    mainTabBarController.view.frame = normalRect;
    [self.window addSubview:mainTabBarController.view];
    [self.window addSubview:detailedNavigationController.view];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.35 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                     animations: ^{
                         detailedNavigationController.view.frame = normalRect;
                         mainTabBarController.view.frame = leftRect;
                     } 
                     completion: ^(BOOL finished){
                         [mainTabBarController.view removeFromSuperview];
                     }];
}

- (void) showMainTabBar
{
    CGRect normalRect = self.window.bounds;
    CGRect rightRect = CGRectOffset(normalRect, normalRect.size.width, 0);
    CGRect leftRect = CGRectOffset(normalRect, -normalRect.size.width, 0);

    mainTabBarController.view.frame = leftRect;
    detailedNavigationController.view.frame = normalRect;
    [self.window addSubview:mainTabBarController.view];
    [self.window addSubview:detailedNavigationController.view];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.35 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                     animations: ^{
                         mainTabBarController.view.frame = normalRect;
                         detailedNavigationController.view.frame = rightRect;
                     } 
                     completion: ^(BOOL finished){
                         [detailedNavigationController.view removeFromSuperview];
                     }];
}
```

I think this solution is better then emulating of tab bar, since it doesn't break `UIViewContoller`'s life cycle.